# FlowLayout not displaying components while GridLayout does?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm making an application to act as a hub of some sorts, where the user can store shortcuts to their favorite applications and easily launch them. I'm having some problems with `FlowLayout`, though. When I use `GridLayout`, the components display perfectly. When I use `FlowLayout`, nothing displays at all.

GridLayout:
[image: GridLayout]

FlowLayout:
[image: FlowLayout]

All I have changed is the `LayoutManager`. When I call `getComponentCount`, they both respond with 9.

I thought this post was pretty long, so I put a snippet of my [code](http://codetidy.com/2955/) on Code Tidy (from Pastebin)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: When you wrote `return new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight());`, whose `Width` and `Height` it is taking into consideration ? If it's the `JComponent` itself, then if you extending `JComponent/JPanel` then it's size is (0, 0) for most of the Layouts. Hence you have to provide some concrete Dimension (some non zero value), for the component to appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) `FlowLayout` pretty accepting `PreferredSize` that came from `JComponent`, each of `JComponents` can have got different `Dimension` on the screen

example (uncomnent `getMinimumSize` & `getMinimumSize`)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CustomComponent extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomComponent() {
        setTitle("Custom Component Test / BorderLayout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }

    public void display() {
        add(new CustomComponents0(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new CustomComponents0(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new CustomComponents0(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new CustomComponents0(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        // enforces the minimum size of both frame and component
        setMinimumSize(getMinimumSize());
        setPreferredSize(getPreferredSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CustomComponent main = new CustomComponent();
                main.display();
            }
        };
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class CustomComponents0 extends JLabel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*@Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(200, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }*/
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

2) `GridLayou`t create proportional area for every `JComponents`, then accepting only `JComponent` that have got larger `Dimnesion` came from `PreferredSize`

3) for `GridLayout` I'm talking about method `pack()`, not if is there `JFrame#setSize()`, for `FLowLayout` doesn't matter,

Comment: I am a noob but when testing your code the IDE can't compile it because of `CustomComponents0`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm I know this has been answered, but just to add, if you look at the code below and run it, it will create 9 labels and 4 buttons and add them using the flow layout, but as with this example below the frames size is set using `setSize(int width,int height)`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FlowLayoutTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel NorthPanel, SouthPanel;
    private JLabel[] labels;
    private JButton[] buttons;

    public FlowLayoutTest() {
        createAndShowUI();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                FlowLayoutTest flowLayoutTest = new FlowLayoutTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        setTitle("Flow layout");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        initializeComponents();
        addComponents(this.getContentPane());

        //pack();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initializeComponents() {

        labels = new JLabel[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            labels[i] = new JLabel("Label " + (i+1));
        }
        buttons = new JButton[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton("Button " + (i+1));
        }

        NorthPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(5));
        SouthPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(5));
    }

    private void addComponents(Container contentPane) {

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            SouthPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            NorthPanel.add(labels[i]);
        }

        contentPane.add(NorthPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        contentPane.add(SouthPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

however when you run the application you will notice a label (number 9) has gone off screen, this is because `setSize()` was used, however if we call(or in this case uncomment) `pack()` before setting the frame to visible, you will be able too see all the components on the frame.

Comment: +1 bet never to returns setSize(), but PreferredSize(), because part of Custom LayoutManagers can shrinking Dimmension wrong way

Comment: Hmmm never thought about it like that eh? +1. Learning new stuff daily

Comment: Is it also possible to have it wrap the labels that don't fit to the next line?