# Components on the JPanel doesn't show

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, preferredsize

I created a JPanel and i modify it a bit. I change it's background to gradient color here is the class.

```
public class JGradientPanel extends JPanel {
     private static final int N = 32;
     private Color color1, color2;
        public JGradientPanel(Color color1, Color color2) {
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(N, N, N, N));

            this.color1 = color1;
            this.color2 = color2;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            //Color color1 = getBackground();
            //Color color2 = color1.darker();
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
}
```

Now i added few components to the panel but it didn't display anything, here is the code

```
public JPanel getMenu() {
        JGradientPanel menu = new JGradientPanel(Color.WHITE, Color.white.darker());
        int menuHeight = (int) ((int) getHeight() * 0.07);
        menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth,menuHeight));
        menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,10));
        menu.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        //test
        JGradientButton test = new JGradientButton("test",Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
        menu.add(test);

        JLabel space = new JLabel(); // first blank space on the menu
        space.setBounds(0, 0, menu.getPreferredSize().width - 50, menu.getPreferredSize().height);
        space.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.GREEN));
        menu.add(space);
        JLabel moreSpaces[] = new JLabel[6];
        buttons = new JButton[buttonLabels.length];
        for(int counter = 0; counter < moreSpaces.length + buttonLabels.length; counter ++ ) {
            if(counter < 3) {
                buttons[counter] = new JButton(buttonLabels[counter]); //menu buttons

            } else {
                moreSpaces[counter - 3] = new JLabel(); // the rest of the blank in the menu
            }
        }
        // adding components to menu panel
        for(int counter = 0; counter < moreSpaces.length + buttonLabels.length; counter ++){
            if(counter < 3) {
                buttons[counter].setFocusPainted(false);
                menu.add(buttons[counter]); 
            } else {
                menu.add(moreSpaces[counter - 3]);
            }

        }
        return menu;
    }
```

Did i miss something or i did it wrong? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is this `JPanel` standalone or added to another `JFrame` or its equivalent? Also, is it set visible?

Comment: It is added to a JFrame.

Comment: When i use a simple JPanel the components shows

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

- override [`getPreferredSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071471/714968) in `public class JGradientPanel extends JPanel {`
- [Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) by `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` by default never to returns [PreferredSize to JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html),
- `JPanel` returns `Dimension[0, 0];`

EDIT

- see very informative and [interesting thread about GradientPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748810/gradient-problems-in-java)

Comment: what exactly will i put on the overridden `getPreferredSize` method?

Comment: (blue) colored text contains links

Comment: `@Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return super.getPreferredSize();
  }` what's missing? i don't quite understand your pointing at, sorry i'm a bit new to this

Comment: return new Dimension(300, 200); (for example) instead of return super.getPreferredSize();, because return super.getPreferredSize(); returns zero Dimension

Comment: you got it right bro.. but now i can't use the `setPreferredSize()` if i modified the `JPanel`? or do i need to override that too so that the `getPreferredSize()` will work according to the `setPreferredSize()`?

Comment: this override to make 1. JPanel resizable with it container 2. all painting could be based on getWeight/getHeight instead of static number, then painting is resizable with JPanel too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28042/discussion-between-user1708134-and-mkorbel)