# Sprite spawning on particular JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, keylistener

I am working on multiplayer game where when the server sends distinct message, ie. type of enemy and number of enemies. that particular sprite loads onto screen. I have 4 views, seperated by CardLayout and buttons on the top to switch between screens.

Here's the chain that I have set up. When I try to draw the enemies.. I get an error.

In Main class I have this method:

```
public void handleAttack(String message){
  ViewA.spawnEnemy(type,amt);
}
```

This is the class for `ViewA` which has the `spawnEnemy()` method.

```
public class BattleView extends JPanel implements ActionListener {  
  private Player player;
  private Timer timer;
  private int B_WIDTH;
  private int B_HEIGHT;
  private boolean ingame;
  private ArrayList aliens;

  public BattleView(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.RED);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);
    setSize(652, 480);
    ingame = true;
    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();
  }

  public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    B_WIDTH = getWidth();
    B_HEIGHT = getHeight();   

    super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT));
  }

  public void spawnEnemy(int type, int amount) {
    aliens = new ArrayList();
    for (int i=1; i<amount+1; i++ ) {
      aliens.add(new Enemy(0-i*40,400));
      System.out.println("Attack Message Recieved "+i);
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

    if (player.isVisible()){
      g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(), this);
    }
    ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();

    /* for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) {
      Missile m = (Missile)ms.get(i);
      g2d.drawImage(m.getImage(), m.getX(), m.getY(), this);
    }*/

    /*    for (int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
      Enemy a = (Enemy)aliens.get(i);
      if (a.isVisible()){
        g2d.drawImage(a.getImage(), a.getX(), a.getY(), this);
      }
    }*/

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawString("BattleView: ", 5, 15);

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
  }

  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    /* if (aliens.size()==0) {
      //send message to server that enemies have been killed
    }*/

    ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();
    /*  for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) {
      Missile m = (Missile) ms.get(i);
      if (m.isVisible()){
        m.move();
      }else{
        ms.remove(i);
      }
    }*/

    /*  for (int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
      Enemy a = (Enemy) aliens.get(i);
      if (a.isVisible()){
        a.move();
      }else{
        aliens.remove(i);
      }
    }*/

    player.move();
    checkCollisions();
    repaint();  
  }

  public void checkCollisions() {
    /* Rectangle r3 = player.getBounds();

    for (int j = 0; j<aliens.size(); j++) {
      Enemy a = (Enemy) aliens.get(j);
      Rectangle r2 = a.getBounds();

        if (r3.intersects(r2)) {
          player.setVisible(false);
          a.setVisible(false);
          ingame = false;
        }
    }*/

    ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();
    /*  for (int i = 0; i < ms.size(); i++) {
      Missile m = (Missile) ms.get(i);

      Rectangle r1 = m.getBounds();
      for (int j = 0; j<aliens.size(); j++) {
        Enemy a = (Enemy) aliens.get(j);
        Rectangle r2 = a.getBounds();

        if (r1.intersects(r2)) {
          m.setVisible(false);
          a.setVisible(false);
        } // r1.intersects
      } // for aliens.size()
    }*/ // for ms.size()
  }

  private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
      player.keyReleased(e);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      player.keyPressed(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This part fires five `System.out.println("Attack Message Recieved "+i);` when server sends message. So if server sends 1,5.. 5 units of type 1 are "recieved" and `System.out.println` prints 5 times.

Now when I try to use `paint(g)` to draw the enemy units using the for-loop.. I get an error When I comment out the for-loop everything compiles fine and loads (but no screen sprites are created of the enemy, only the `System.out.println` fires the N number of times sent via the server.

How can I get it to draw the enemies right after the `System.out.println` fires?

This is the error:

```
at ViewA.paint(ViewA.java:85)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

at ViewA.paint(ViewA.java:85)

corresponds to this line:

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
>             Enemy a = (Enemy)aliens.get(i);
>             if (a.isVisible())
>                 g2d.drawImage(a.getImage(), a.getX(), a.getY(), this);
>         }
>
>         g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
>         g2d.drawString("BattleView: ", 5, 15);
> ```

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `paint(g)` yourself, use `repaint` to request that the panel be repainted

Comment: can you remove commented lines, that aren't necessary?

Comment: Okay that tells us where not what...included the actual exception as well (I know, we're meanies)

Answer (score 1):

Start by trying to call `repaint` to request that the panel should be repainted...

```
public void spawnEnemy(int type, int amount) {
    aliens = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 1; i < amount + 1; i++) {
        aliens.add(new Enemy(0 - i * 40, 400));
        System.out.println("Attack Message Recieved " + i);
    }
    repaint() // <<-- 
}
```

Also, it is recommended that should be overriding `paintComponent` instead of `paint`

**Updated**

Don't dispose of any resource you didn't create...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //  g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    if (player.isVisible()) {
        g2d.drawImage(player.getImage(), player.getX(), player.getY(),
                this);
    }
    ArrayList ms = player.getMissiles();
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.drawString("BattleView: ", 5, 15);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    // This is a bad idea..
    //g.dispose();
}
```

`Graphics` is a shared resource, meaning that other components in your application may need to use them.  Also disposing may prevent Swing from begin able to paint anything at all...

**Updated**

You define a `ArrayList` as an instance field, but you never initialise until the `spawnEnemy` method is called.  `paint` is likely to called a long time before that.

```
public class BattleView extends JPanel implements ActionListener {  
    //...//
    private ArrayList aliens;

    //..//

    public void spawnEnemy(int type, int amount) {
        aliens = new ArrayList();
```

You have a number of options.  You could check for to see if the `aliens` list is `null` before painting...

```
if (aliens != null) { ... }
```

But there is a problem here, what happens if you get more enemies?  You could actually lose some (if `paint` isn't called before more updates arrive)

Instead, you should create the `aliens` list in the constructor and simply update it as new enemies arrive...

```
public BattleView(Player player) {
    aliens = new ArrayList();
    //...//
}
```

Add new enemies to the list as they arrive...

```
public void spawnEnemy(int type, int amount) {
    for (int i=1; i<amount+1; i++ ) {
        aliens.add(new Enemy(0-i*40,400));
        System.out.println("Attack Message Recieved "+i);
    }
    repaint();
}
```

And then paint...

```
for (int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
    Enemy a = (Enemy)aliens.get(i);
    if (a.isVisible())
        g2d.drawImage(a.getImage(), a.getX(), a.getY(), this);
}
```

Comment: Tried that.. The error I am having is here:

    `for (int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
                Enemy a = (Enemy)aliens.get(i);
                if (a.isVisible())
                    g2d.drawImage(a.getImage(), a.getX(), a.getY(), this);
            }`

Comment: There is the possibility of a mutable update, ie, you might add new enemies to the aliens list while you are painting them..

Comment: Updated post.. check now

Comment: Okay that tells us where not what...included the actual exception as well (I know, we're meanies)

Comment: I am completely confused.. been trying to figure this out last 5 hours.. can't get it to work

Comment: I know the feeling, but without the actually description of the exception (which should appear before the stack trace), it's difficult to pin point the problem...

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Don't forget to take into consideration the comments made by myself and mkorbel

Answer (score 1):

from the top

EDIT

1. `timer = new Timer(5, this);` 5 miliseconds is refresh frequency under `latency for all Native OS`, you can to play with amount at 25 or more

   ---
2. remove whole code block `public void addNotify() {` and to replace with [getPreferredSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071471/714968) then,

   a) all coordinates are based on get `width`/`height`

   b) `Objects` painted in `JPanel` are/could be resizable with `JFrame`
3. use `paintComponent` for Swing JComponent and custom painting in Java instead of  `public void paint(Graphics g) {`
4. `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {` missing code line `repaint()` for programatically repainting
5. don't to use  `KeyListener` for `Swing JComponents`, use `KeyBindings` added to `JPanel` instead of `KeyListener`,